# Correct Associations Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Can someone help me to correct my associations ?

I have the following models:

```
User, Developer, Application, Comments, Rating, Permission
```

Requirements:

```
A user can be a Developer or not.
A user can have Default Permissions and Permissions for each application
A user can install multiple Applications
A user can comment and rate multiple Applications
A developer can develop multiple applications
An application can request a list of permissions.
```

I already created some associations but I believe its not 100% correct or an easier way to do it exist.

Can someone suggest me a correct way to do it?

Comment: Why is developer its own model? If a user can *be* a developer, whether or not it's a developer should be a boolean field on the user.

Comment: Yes. But if it is a developer then he can owns some applications. I also had a Developer Profile model. Thanks why I believe that I am doing something wrong. I have too much models!

Comment: Can you paste your current db schema? It's in db/schema.rb

Answer (score 14):

You are confusing models with authorization.

You should check out CanCan for role based authorization. For example you don't need your developer model since its just a user with a different role/permissions.

Edit: Changed 'role based authentication' to 'role based authorization'. As the comment below points out the difference between authentication and authorization.

Comment: And you confused authentication (who am I) with authorization (what can I do). :)

Comment: Kinda... but not really. You need a login/user model (authentication) to answer the who am I part. But the user model with cancan also contains a role column which can map to admin/guest/whatever. This role column provides cancan with authentication (answering the who am I) in order to provide authorization (what can I do).

Comment: woops didn't realize I had put 'role based authentication' in the second paragraph. Changed to more accurately reflect what I meant. Thanks Jeremy :)

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you want as far as your model work. You can use a join model to manage your application permissions, and use Rails STI to manage what each type of user can do, whether it's developing or not.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps
  has_many :comments, :through => :user_comments
  has_many :ratings, :through => :user_ratings
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

rating.rb

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user_comment.rb

```
class UserComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

user_rating.rb

```
class UserRating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

normal_user.rb (STI)

```
class NormalUser < User
end
```

developer.rb (STI)

```
class Developer < User
end
```

app.rb

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, :through => :app_permissions
  has_many :user_comments
  has_many :user_ratings
end
```

permission.rb

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

app_permission.rb

```
class AppPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: Your normal user would have default permissions, so you can set your permissions in user.rb. Or for controller access you can do things like "if @user.is_a?(NormalUser)", applicable to the view as well

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. What about User who has default permissions? And Users who can have specific permissions for an application?? In addition Developers can have many apps. Can I add has_many :app in developer.rb and belongs_to :developer in application??

Comment: Finally is it possible for a user to be a normal user and developer at the same time using this paradigm?

Comment: I wouldn't use STI for User/Developer. Developer is a role, not something other than a user.

Comment: So what do you suggest @Mark? Can you provide an example similar to the above please? I am new to Ruby and I believe that learning through examples is the easiest way.

Comment: I suggest you skip the NormalUser and Developer classes, and instead read how to set up authorization via "cancan":http://asciicasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: I believe that, using CanCan will not be advantageous for my issue. Because, I want a user to be able to become a developer as soon as he create his first application not by using a predefined access role and only the developer will be able to edit application information. A developer will still be a normal user and still be able to install applications.

Comment: to address you has_many :apps for developers, you don't need to since developer inherits from User, and a User has_many :apps. In addition, STI may help if you want to introduce another type of User like a Moderator, or Admin, or something.

Comment: @ntenisOT, cancan defines "abilities" which isn't necessarily predefined roles. This is far more flexible than a completely different subclass of User. I can tell you from experience, using STI for this will be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: If CanCan can do it simpler, then totally agree with @Mark Thomas

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Mark, don't use STI. The better way will be implement as suggested by @Chris Barretto except for STI and use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for role based authentication. The change for User model will be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :apps
    has_many :comments, :through => :user_comments
    has_many :ratings, :through => :user_ratings
    has_many :roles
end
```

And there will be another model for Role:

```
class Role  < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

If you are using gems like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, it will be much easy.